# Bluetooth And Wifi Not Responding

Tags: wi-fi, bluetooth

I Have Q mobile A50 (Andriod Ver: 4.1.1) It Had Missed Its I.P Address And Due To It. its The Bluetooth  And Wifi Is Not Being Enabled . I.P Adress Is Also Not Showing Can Any One Help Me To Recover It . 
Here A Picture of it.[image]

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I.P address can not cause Bluetooth or MAC address to disappear.

Secondly to see your IP address you must have data enabled, same goes for bluetooth and wifi, you have to switch them on first

I still dont understand why you had to write "Not responding" and then post a status image, be more specific on your problem

Edit:
See the pictures below as I enable each component, notice the status bar

[image]

[image]

Comment: What you are viewing there is just status info, "Unavailable" doesnt mean "Not Working" unless you have tried switching them on and failed....if not then go to Settings and enable the appropiate component.....and please use comments